# Separate GitHub Pages URL for each allure report generated via GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, github-pages, allure

I have this workflow to generate allure reports and deploy on gh-pages:

```
  - name: Generate Allure report
    run: |
      allure generate allure-raw -o allure-report

  - name: Generate timestamp
    id: timestamp
    run: echo "::set-output name=timestamp::$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"

  - name: Create reports directory
    run: mkdir -p uireports/${{ steps.timestamp.outputs.timestamp }}

  - name: Copy Allure report
    run: |
      mkdir -p uireports/${{ steps.timestamp.outputs.timestamp }}
      cp -R allure-report/. uireports/${{ steps.timestamp.outputs.timestamp }}

  - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
    uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
    with:
      github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      publish_dir: uireports/${{ steps.timestamp.outputs.timestamp }}
      publish_branch: gh-pages
      force_orphan: true
```

and after generation of reports another workflow in triggered to build and deploy the reports:

[image: workflow graph]

But this report is overridden after each run. I want to preserve all the reports accessible via their respective URLs.

I tried achieving it through copying it at a folder based on timestamp and generate URL as:

```
- name: Get GitHub Pages URL
  id: get_pages_url
  run: |
    echo "URL=https://${{ github.repository_owner }}.github.io/${{ github.repository }}/uireports/${{ steps.timestamp.outputs.timestamp }}/index.html" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

but this is not working, giving 404.

Comment: Have you tried not to force orphans? https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages#%EF%B8%8F-force-orphan-force_orphan

Comment: Yes i tried this option also. I mean not to force orphans

Comment: Have you tried to keep existing files? https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages#%EF%B8%8F-keeping-existing-files-keep_files